# How to remove the error tip after jquery.datepicker

Tags: jquery, validation, datetime

I have an input like `<input name="begin_time" />,<input name="end_time" />` I'm using the jquery.datepicker and jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js to get the datetime.

```
$('input[name=begin_time]').datetimepicker({
        minDate : 0,
        stepMinute : 5,
        beforeShow : function (input, inst) {},
        onClose : function (dateText, inst) {
            var endDateTextBox = $('input[name=end_time]');
            var beginDateTextBox = $('input[name=begin_time]');
            var testStartDate = new Date(dateText);
            if (endDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testEndDate = new Date(endDateTextBox.val());
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            } else {
                endDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        onSelect : function (selectedDateTime) {
            var start = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
            $('input[name=end_time]').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(start.getTime()));
        }
    });
    $('input[name=end_time]').datetimepicker({
        onClose : function (dateText, inst) {
            var startDateTextBox = $('input[name=begin_time]');
            if (startDateTextBox.val() != '') {
                var testStartDate = new Date(startDateTextBox.val());
                var testEndDate = new Date(dateText);
                if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                    startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            } else {
                startDateTextBox.val(dateText);
            }
        },
        stepMinute : 5,
        onSelect : function (selectedDateTime) {
            var end = $(this).datetimepicker('getDate');
            $('input[name=begin_time]').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(end.getTime()));
        }
    });
```

I'm also using the jquery.validate.js to validate the input, and make sure it is required before I submit the form.

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules : {
        begin_time : 'required',
                end_time : 'required'
    },
    messages : {
        begin_time : 'The  start time can\' be empty',
                end_time : 'The event end time can\' be empty'
    }
})
```

When the user does not fill in anything, I submit , then the message appears ( it is right).

But when I pickup the datetime, the error tips still does not disappear. I want it disappear.

Can anyone give me a suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `focusCleanup` to get rid of any error classes and messages.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   focusCleanup: true
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$("#dateFieldID").change(function () {
    $('#formID').validate({
        required: true,
        date: true
    }).element('#dateFieldID');
});
```

Adding an **change** event to each date picker input field and then validating removed the field for me. I tested this in Firefox 17, IE 7+, Safari 6 and Chrome v.23. I've seen other posts where developers suggest hooking into the JQuery UI DatePicker onClose event and then setting the focus back to the date field when the onClose event is dispatched. This did *work*, however, in IE the DatePicker dialog wouldn't hide. Also, the error message only disappeared AFTER the date field lost focus - which wasn't consistent with other fields. This did the trick for me.

I hope this helps someone. This appears to be working well - for me at least ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solutions here at the time didn't work for me. What did work was adding the onSelect below to validate the date field when a date is selected from the date picker:

```
$("#dateFieldID").datepick({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function () {
        $("#dateFieldID").valid();
    }
});
```

Comment: valid() is not a function